# Can we find a set so that it satisfies first and second axioms only with $0=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

I was reading the definition of Field and it says this:

[image: Field]

Now by definition $F^{\times}=F-\{0\}$. So there is no question of $0=1$. (And somehow if I use that $0=1$, I can not have the third axiom, since it will follow every element of $F$ are same.)

More generally the third axiom connects the two group structure, namely the additive group and the multiplicative group.

> **My question:**
>
> Can we find a non-trivial set (say $F^*$) so that it satisfies first and second axioms only with $0=1$? (a trivial example would be $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$)

Comment: In (ii), how can the 'identity element' of $F^\times=F-\{0\}$ be an element that's not even in that group? (Since it will have been removed assuming $0=1$)

Comment: Not sure if I understand but let $a\in F$ and suppose $1=0 $ then $  0= a\cdot 0= a\cdot 1 = a$

Comment: If $0 = 1$ you can prove that the trivial example is all that can possibly exist.  $a = a*1 = a*0 = a(1 + (-1)) = a + (-1) = 0$.

Comment: Your example of $\{0\}$ would make $F^\times$ empty in $(ii)$, but groups are nonempty sets by definition.

Comment: @fleablood That uses distributivity law, which OP doesn't want to force.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki if $1=0$, we can not have $F^{\times}=F-\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes, you must give up distributive law if you want non-trivality. If you give up distributive law there is nothing "connecting" the operations to each other.  i.e. you just have two unrelated groups that share elements.

Comment: That... is.  Let X and Y be two completely different groups with the same number of elements.  Label the elements so the have to same labels. Call one "addition" the other multiplication.  That's it.

Comment: @fleablood I guess you are right. The realization I am getting of **the point why we need field** is because we need to "connect" to addition and multiplication, to do that we need third axiom. If not then nothing really special!!!

Comment: Exactly.  $F - {0}|\cdot$ is just an abelian group.  And $F|+$ is just another.  They have nothing to do with each other. To relate them we need $a(b+c) = ab + ac$.  We get a problem that if $\frac 10*0 = 1$ then $\frac 10*0*a=a$ but $a*0 + a*0 = a*0$ so $0*a = 0$ and $a = 1$ so $0$ can't have a multiplicative inverse unless it is trivial.  And $1 \ne 0$ unless it is trivial.... Or this are not groups.  It is possible to have rings that have 0 divisors.  But then not all elements have inverses (indeed the identity may not exist.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a field with $0 = 1$, it can be be proven such a field must be trivial (contains only the single element $0$.)

For any $a \in F$ then $a = a*1 = a*0 = 0$.  So $\{a \in F\} = \{0\}$.

Of course, this assumes $a*0 = 0$ which can be proven for all fields.

[$a*0 = a(0 + 0) = a*0 + a*0$

so $0= a*0 + (-(a*0)) = a*0 + a*0 + (-(a*0)) = a*0 + (a*0 + (-(a*0)) = a*0 + 0 = a*0$.]

(Of course "field" by definition can't have $0 = 1$.  But if we ignore that condition but kept all other axioms, such a "field-like structure" with $0=1$ would have to be trivial.)

====

Okay, rereading your post.  The third axiom is the *only* axiom that relates the group $F;+$ to the group $F-\{0\}; \cdot$ in any way.  Without it, we can have the group $\mathbb Z_6, +$ where $e=0=1\approx 0;a\approx1; b\approx2;c\approx3;d\approx4;f\approx5$.  And we can have the unrelated group $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_3$ where $e=0=1\approx (0,0); c\approx(0,1); b\approx(1,0);f\approx(1,1);a\approx(2,0);d\approx(2,1)$.  Thus we have $b(c + a) = bd=c$ but $bc + b*a= f + e=f$

But there is utterly nothing of "meaning" to such a construction.

Comment: But obviously what I am saying is not a field. And can you write those step without using third axiom??(because that was what my point was)

Comment: I guess you are right. The realization I am getting of the point why we need field is because we need to "connect" to addition and multiplication, to do that we need third axiom. If not then nothing really special!!!

Comment: thanks, now I can sleep in peace (ha ha)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure quite what you mean. But if you were to make a structure with four elements, you could define 'addition' by the cyclic group and 'multiplication' by the four group (abelian group of order four in which all non-identity elements have order $2$). You can identify the identity elements of these groups. They would have no interaction with each other - it is the compatibility through the distributive law which is the point most of the time.